# Which criteria decides how to map modules to components for Angular2?

Tags: angular, web-component, angular-cli, ng-modules

How modules are distributed on components. and what are the advantages of this new concept over simple folder organisation ?

**Options:**

- One module per component ?
- One module per page.
- Other ...

Comment: Did you read https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html

Comment: but I find myself obliged to create a module per component to be able to export them to be used for parent components !

Comment: Why do you find yourself obliged to create a module per component? You can put as many components into a module as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Components, directives, pipes, and services should be grouped together per feature. If they are usually (re)used together, they should be in the same module.

A module can be lazy loaded. If you want a part of your application to be lazy loaded, then put the components, ...,  that build that part of your application in such a module, or import modules that contain the components, ..., only from such a lazy loaded module.

Comment: but I find myself obliged to create a module per component to be able to export them to be used for parent components !